# All Files in Xcode Project Appear as "A" or "?"

Tags: xcode, version-control

I have a Xcode project which is displaying an "A" or a "?" in the source control section to the right of every file. This is despite committing all changes. Performing a "git status" shows the working tree is clean.  The problem is more of an ease of use issue, as this just makes it hard to see which files I have been modifying, as usually modified files show "M" and everything else is blank.

Tried restarting Xcode and cleaning project.